# are existential formula also quantifier free formula?

Tags: logic

I was reading lecture notes, as showed in the picture. I think it should be sufficient to show that existential formula should also be quantifier free. How may I show it or am I completely lost?

[image: question itself, and related definitions]

Answer (score 2):

Quantifier-free formulas are existential formulas (take $m = 0$ in the linked definition), but the converse is not true.